# Short question concerning derivation of Measure for non continuous CDF

Tags: probability, derivatives

This might be totally trivial, but it puzzles me nevertheless:

Let $F(x)$ be the CDF of $X \sim U[0,1]$. Let $\Delta(x)= \{ \begin{matrix} 0 \quad x<1/3 \\ 1/3 \quad 1/3\leq x <2/3 \\ 2/3 \quad 2/3 \leq  x <1 \\ 1 \quad 1 \leq x \end{matrix}$.

Define

$G(x) = \int_0^{min(x,\Delta(x))} f(t) dt = F(min(x,\Delta(x))$

If G was continuous we could just take derivatives to get the density g. Since G is not continuous, I struggle to derive the measure dG as a function of f or F. Is there anybody who could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Two suggestions: (i) Capitalize random variables $X$ to make them distinct from the values $x$ that they take. (ii) It is not clear if you intend $G(x)$ (or $G(X)$) to be a number or a random variable. Also, you may want to use $f(t)dt$ in the integral to avoid yet-a-third-type-of-x.

Comment: thank you, I hope it’s clear now

Comment: It seems like $\Delta(x) \leq x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, so, why do you write $\min[x, \Delta(x)]$ and not just $\Delta(x)$?  In fact, assuming $f(t)=1$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, it looks like $G(x) = \Delta(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: $\Delta(x)$ is just the CDF of a discrete random variable $Z$ with $P[Z=1/3]=P[Z=2/3]=P[Z=1]=1/3$.